# Como exibir/ocultar conteúdo de uma página de acordo com o "status HTTP" do site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http

tenho o seguinte problema...

Cenário: Um site com entrega de páginas apenas em HTML (não podemos utilizar uma linguagem server-side).

Efetuamos um embed de vídeo do Youtube, porém algumas empresas como sabemos, bloqueiam o acesso de seus funcionários a redes sociais. Ocorre que no frame do youtube (embed) aparece a mensagem de conteúdo bloqueado.

Uma das soluções possíveis seria a identificação do status HTTP e se retornar 200, exibimos o frame com o embed do Youtube. Senão, ocultamos o frame e é exibida apenas a imagem de background, não sendo exibido o erro pro usuário que não tem acesso.

É possível fazer isso apenas com o uso de javascript?

Comment: Acredito que vc teria que fazer a solicitação do vídeo via Ajax.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso aqui, acho que a solução é por aí: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/lazyytjs-a-jquery-plugin-to-lazy-load-youtube-videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que você está usando um frame Embed, através da [API javascript](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), para controlar o Player, então provavelmente o *callback* `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` nunca é invocado com o vídeo bloqueado.

Não sei o comportamento da API nessa situação, por isso não posso dar uma resposta definitiva, mas imagino o seguinte cenário para alcançar seu objeto:

1. Inicialmente, mostre apenas uma imagem de carregamento do vídeo.
2. Se o método *callback* for chamado, tomamos por base que o `iframe` inicializou corretamente, então mostre o vídeo .
3. Se, após um certo tempo (*timeout*), o evento não for chamado, então mostrar a imagem final substituindo o vídeo.

Comment: A questão de incluir a imagem inicialmente, também cogitamos, mas você complementou com um item que não falamos sobre. De qualquer forma, já deu uma "luz"... :)